# Collapsiblock module - can I have horizontal expanding tabs instead of vertical?

Tags: blocks

Collapsiblock: http://drupal.org/project/collapsiblock

I am looking for a way to allow the sidebar blocks to be collapsible left-to-right instead of top-to-bottom using the Collapsiblock module. It would basically be a way to hide the left and right-column blocks until someone clicks the tab, after which the block would expand to the width of the column. It seems as though it should be a fairly straightforward change in the JS file, but I cannot figure it out. Can anyone here provide any insight into this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search `slideUp` and `slideDown` in `collapsiblock.js`and replace with `animate`, for example:

```
$(this.target).animate({width:'toggle'},slidespeed);
```

Useful post: [Slide Elements in Different Directions](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks!

To anyone wondering, I replaced the code in lines 36-42 and 53-59 with this:

$(this.target).animate({width:'toggle'},slidespeed);

It'll take some CSS styling to get it looking right, but this does take care of the functionality.